# Expand scala splat at compile time using macros and eval

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I have a sequence, `val xs: Seq[T]`, and a function `f(xs: T*)`.

I'd like to write a macro that expands `f(xs: _*)` to `f(x1, x2, ... xn)` at compile time, but I'm having a lot of trouble successfully `eval`ing the `Expr` in the macro. I've tried a few different approaches. `scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox` complains about `c.universe` not matching the runtime universe. `c.eval(...)` complains that the tree has already been typechecked, and running `c.untypecheck` just gives me more type errors.

Comment: Are you aware that a macro receives trees, and that repeating args are already supplied as a Seq? You might have better luck on gitter clarifying those questions.

Comment: If repeating args are supplied as a Seq at compile time, why does `f(xs)` fail to typecheck and `f(xs: _*)` succeed? What exactly is the `_*` doing?

Comment: In any case, if that's true the problem becomes evaluating and expanding a `Seq` into an argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sequence arg" defined http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#function-applications

Your macro sees https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-RC1/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/TreeInfo.scala#L578

```
scala> import reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

scala> def f[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(arg: c.Expr[A]*) = { import c.universe._ ; println(arg.map(x => showRaw(x.tree))) ; q"${arg.size}" } 
f: [A](c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context)(arg: c.Expr[A]*)(implicit evidence$1: c.WeakTypeTag[A])c.universe.Tree

scala> def g[A](arg: A*): Int = macro f[A]
defined term macro g: [A](arg: A*)Int

scala> val xs = List(1,2,3)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> g(xs, 42)
List(Select(Select(Select(Select(Ident($line16), $line16.$read), $line16.$read.$iw), $line16.$read.$iw.$iw), TermName("xs")), Literal(Constant(42)))
res0: Int = 2

scala> g(42, xs: _*)
List(Literal(Constant(42)), Typed(Select(Select(Select(Select(Ident($line16), $line16.$read), $line16.$read.$iw), $line16.$read.$iw.$iw), TermName("xs")), Ident(typeNames.WILDCARD_STAR)))
res1: Int = 2

scala> g(1,2,3)
List(Literal(Constant(1)), Literal(Constant(2)), Literal(Constant(3)))
res2: Int = 3
```

Runtime code sees:

```
scala> def count[A](as: A*): Int = as.size
count: [A](as: A*)Int

scala> count(xs)
res4: Int = 1

scala> count(xs: _*)
res5: Int = 3
```